# Html head tags appearing in ui-views when using Angular-ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

So i'm using angular-ui-router instead of the default angular router

And for some reason my ui-view is being duplicated and outputting the  tag contents in the body of my page

```
(function(window){
var angular = window.angular;
angular.module('mean', ['ui.router', 'mean.auth'])
.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    $stateProvider
        .state('mean', {
            abstract: true,
            views: {
                navbar: {
                    templateUrl: 'views/main/views/navbar.html',
                    controller: 'navCtrl'
                },
                '': {
                    templateUrl: '<ui-view/>'
                },
                footer: {
                    templateUrl: 'views/main/views/footer.html',
                    controller: 'footCtrl'
                }
            }
        })
        .state('mean.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'views/main/views/home.html',
            controller: 'homeCtrl'
        })
        .state('mean.login', {
            url: '/login',
            templateUrl: 'views/auth/views/login.html',
            controller: 'loginCtrl'
        })
        .state('mean.register', {
            url: '/register',
            templateUrl: 'views/auth/views/register.html',
            controller: 'registerCtrl'
        })
}])
}(window));
```

the code for this is at my github https://github.com/sceptre12/MeanTraining please help

Comment: Okay I found out the issue, The reason was because i accidentally put templateUrl: <ui-view/>. For some reason instead of throwing an error it just renders a view with the head content inside of the body tag. The fix is obvious, using template: <ui-view/> but I still feel an error should be thrown whenever regular html is being rendered out from templateUrl

Answer (score 0):

There are some gaps between this code right here and your repository.

Based on your repository, you're adding a view, inside your 'mean' state, with a templateUrl that points at the index.html itself: that can be a problem and that's why you see duplicated html tags in your DOM.

Comment: Sorry, I was trying as many things as possible to try and rectify the issue, but no matter what the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found out the issue, The reason was because i accidentally put templateUrl: . For some reason instead of throwing an error it just renders a view with the head content inside of the body tag. The fix is obvious, using template:  but I still feel an error should be thrown whenever regular html is being rendered out from templateUrl